# Invalid URI when making a request to backend with create-react-app

Tags: request, axios, create-react-app

I am making a ReactJS front-end app, using create-react-app, I have set up my proxy and made sure it is working by testing with a REST API client (Insomnia). For some reason, when the request is made from the browser, it fails with status code  500, and the reason given is "Ivalid URL". I have tried it using a different browser on the development machine, deleting the node_modules folder, used to different request libraries, even reinstalling create-react-app and creating the project structure from scratch, but I can't seem to get it to work. The weirdest part of all is that the app works as written on my laptop.

I have set up my proxy like this:

```
const proxy = require ('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports =function (app){
    console.log("Se ejecutó el setupProxy");
    app.use(proxy("/register", {target:"http://localhost:3001"}));
    app.use(proxy("/auth/local", {target:"http://localhost:3001"}));
    app.use(proxy("/api/current_user", {target:"http://localhost:3001"}));
}
```

My request from the front end, made in one of my Redux Action Creators looks like this:

```
export function registerUser(userInfo)
{
    return async (dispatch) =>
    {
        /*axios.post("/register",{
        display_name: userInfo.username,
        password: userInfo.password,
        email: userInfo.email,
    }).then((resp)=>{
        dispatch({type: USER_REGISTRATION, payload:"User Registered"});    
    }).catch((error)=>{
        dispatch({type: USER_REGISTRATION,payload:error.response.data.message});
    });*/
    rp.post('/register',{json:true,formData:{
        display_name: userInfo.username,
        password: userInfo.password,
        email: userInfo.email
    }}).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log("Error ha ocurrido:");
        console.log(err);
    });

};

}
```

Notice that I have tried with both axios and request.js. Axios does not return a body, and Request.js simply returns a status code 500 and an Invalid URL message.

What am I doing wrong? Why does this work on one machine, but not in another? Please, I am at my wit's end with this. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by cloning my repository from scratch on a different folder and installing the dependencies again into the new copy. I still don't know why this happened, but this solved it.

Answer (score 2):

With create react app you can add a `proxy` property to your `package.json`.  No need to use a third party library.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "localhost:3001", //this is your back end port
```

More info can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: When I started this project, I tried to configure the proxy this way but it didn't work. I had to follow the instructions on that very page you shared which instructs me to create a setupProxy.js file in the project directory. This works fine on other computers, and as I mentioned, when using a REST client to test the app, requests are proxied correctly. The issue here is that the browser doesn't seem to recognize /register as a valid url, even though it is.

Comment: I'd take out the setupProxy.js file and try again with the proxy property in your package.json of your create-react-app.  Make sure that your server is running on a different port than your webpack server.  So if the client (React) is on port 3000 make sure your backend is running on port 5000 or something different.